# Implementing font for website?

Tags: html, css

I'm Using font "AR CENA" in my CSS but it's not loading the font when browsing the website, for me it's working well, but I think because I already install the font, so it load it from my PC,

Is there a way to implement this font and appear in the website normally for users ?

```
 #u2966-5 {
    z-index: 500;
    width: 125px;
    min-height: 16px;
    background-color: transparent;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #fe9d2b;
    font-family: "AR CENA", open-sans, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: 270px;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look into the CSS rule [@font-face](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_typography). You may not be able to use that exact font (You have to wary of potential licensing issues and what you are allowed to do with a font) but Google has a great font repository that you could use to find something similar, or I personally use font squirrel to download the @font-face kits

[About @font-face](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/@font-face)

[Google fonts](https://developers.google.com/fonts/)

[Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/)

Font Squirrel also has a great web font generator, so if you are sure that you are respecting the fonts EULA you can upload it and the font squirrel generator will convert it to web formats (there is several formats as different browsers support different formats) and give you the CSS ready to go.

I use custom fonts quite a bit and have found the browser support to be very good, even in some of the earlier versions of [Internet Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer). I think I recall reading that IE supported custom fonts back as far as IE 4.