# Using Hindi Font in HTML Websites

Tags: javascript, php, html, fonts, font-face

I want to create a website in hindi font. for this i have tried `@font-family: "Kruti Dev"` etc. but I feel that this website will require hindi font on every user's pc.

What's the best way to use hindi font on a website ?

Comment: What about downloading the font then include it in your project? So that user that do not have the font can still view it in "Hindi" font

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css font family issue, what if the font is not available on client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22238999/css-font-family-issue-what-if-the-font-is-not-available-on-client-side)

Answer (score 4):

use meta tag

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hindi Font का उपयोग</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>We Can Use Hindi Font</h1>
    <p>इस Page में हम हिन्दी भाषा का उपयोग करेंगे</p>
    <h1>We Can also use Hindi Hex Code</h1>
    <p>&#x0907;&#x0938;&nbsp;Page&nbsp;&#x092E;&#x0947;&#x0902;&nbsp;&#x0939;&#x092E;&nbsp;&#x0939;&#x093F;&#x0928;&#x094D;&#x0926;&#x0940;&nbsp;&#x092D;&#x093E;&#x0937;&#x093E;&nbsp;&#x0909;&#x092A;&#x092F;&#x094B;&#x0917;&nbsp;&#x0915;&#x0930;&#x0947;&#x0902;&#x0917;&#x0947;</p>
    
    <a href="https://www.anirdesh.com/gujarati/hindi-unicode.php"><h1>Hindi Code Entity</h1></a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

One way that I can think of is to use [`@font-face`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp).  But you must download the font first then include it in the files of the website

```
@font-face {
    font-family: KrutiDev;
    src: url(path/to/kruti_dev.woff);
}
```

Comment: krutidev.ttf i have used.it is working. but if someone open this website and kruti dev is not exist on his pc then. so please tell me the best method.

Comment: Did you use `@font-face`?

Answer (score 2):

use meta tag in head section

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hindi Font का उपयोग</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>We Can Use Hindi Font</h1>
    <p>इस Page में हम हिन्दी भाषा का उपयोग करेंगे</p>
    <h1>We Can also use Hindi Hex Code</h1>
    <p>&#x0907;&#x0938;&nbsp;Page&nbsp;&#x092E;&#x0947;&#x0902;&nbsp;&#x0939;&#x092E;&nbsp;&#x0939;&#x093F;&#x0928;&#x094D;&#x0926;&#x0940;&nbsp;&#x092D;&#x093E;&#x0937;&#x093E;&nbsp;&#x0909;&#x092A;&#x092F;&#x094B;&#x0917;&nbsp;&#x0915;&#x0930;&#x0947;&#x0902;&#x0917;&#x0947;</p>
    
    <a href="https://www.anirdesh.com/gujarati/hindi-unicode.php"><h1>Hindi Code Entity</h1></a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you send output please

Comment: adding `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` in header worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> You can develop a website in Hindi – or any other language – by
>   embedding custom dynamic fonts. Although, embedding custom fonts has
>   always been a painful experience for web developers and designers, but
>   the latest trends in web design brought the idea back to life with new
>   techniques. In this article you’ll find the modern techniques that may
>   help you with the topic at hand, however, one must note that no
>   particular technique is perfectly compatible with every browser and
>   each has its pros and cons.

You should definitely read this -

http://www.zapbuild.com/bitsntricks/how-to-develop-a-website-in-hindi/

Answer (score 0):

Get the text you want in Hindi using google translate,I usually do it by typing sentences in English and get its translation in the desired language.
And all you need to do is include the following line in the `head` tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="mr">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="mr">  
        
    <style type="text/css">  
        @font-face {
            font-family: KrutiDev;
            src: url(fonts/marathi/k010/k010.woff);
        }
        /*Download Zip file for KrutiDev woff font from internet, Unzip it, Paste 
          the folder in your website folder. I have taken k010*/
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea name="paragraph1" id="paragraph1"  rows="5" cols="80" 
     style="font-family: KrutiDev;color:#003399;">                                                        
    </textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We can write Hindi or English text in Textarea in a webpage using Krutidev web font.  lang="mr".  Here mr for Marathi, hi for hindi.  Specify charset=UTF-8 in head tag. Declare @font-face in style tag.  Use style="font-family: KrutiDev" in textarea.

Comment: Are you aware of the possibility to add into to the answer itself via [edit]ing?

Answer (score -1):

Use google web fonts 'Ek-Mukta': [link here](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Ek+Mukta)

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ek+Mukta" rel="stylesheet">
font-family: 'Ek Mukta', sans-serif;
```

Comment: i added above you share. but how to write in hindi using ek mukta.

Comment: means html page still displaying english not hindi. please give me small example please brother